# How to add a new object to a list without a variable?

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

I am trying to add a new instance of my asd class to a list by constructing a new asd and then adding that, but Unity gives an Object not set to instance of object error.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class asd {
    public int a = 0;
    public string s = "asd";

    public asd (int apop, string ssdf) {
        a = apop;
        s = ssdf;
    }
}

public class test : MonoBehaviour {

    public List<asd> list;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        list.Add (new asd(1, "yeee"));
        list.Add (new asd(456, "oooo"));
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

Comment: @MXD This looks like a quick code example as the name is `test`.

Comment: @MXD Your comment is not constructive and rude.

Comment: Yes it is a test, that is why the names are all terrible

Comment: You should click edit and change it to carefully-considered example names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instantiate your list correctly as below then add `asd` to it

```
public List<asd> list = new List<asd>();

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
      list.Add(new asd(1, "yeee"));
      list.Add(new asd(456, "oooo"));
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public List<asd> list;
```

This says what `list` is, it doesn't instantiate it:

```
public List<asd> list = new List<asd>();
```

Note that class-names should start with a capital letter (PascalCase).